# Compare histograms in OpenCV and normalize similarity index

Tags: c, opencv, histogram

I'm using the last version of OpenCV framework (`2.4.6.0`) for image processing.
I have to compare two histograms to obtain a `float` in the set `[0;1]`, when `0` is the minimum and `1` the maximum value of similarity.

My code is as follows:

```
CvHistogram* create_histogram( IplImage** image, IplImage* mask )
{
    int num_bins = 8;
    float xranges[] = { 0, 255 };
    float* ranges[] = { xranges, xranges, xranges };
    int hist_size[] = { num_bins, num_bins, num_bins };
    CvHistogram* hist = cvCreateHist(3, hist_size, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, 1);
    cvCalcHist(image, hist, 0, mask);
    cvNormalizeHist(hist, 1);
    return hist;
}

void set_histogram( T_FRAME &frame, T_FRAME &mask, T_APPEARANCE &appearance, const T_RECT rect )
{
    cvSetImageROI(frame, rect);
    cvSetImageROI(mask, rect);
    IplImage* b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), frame->depth, 1);
    IplImage* g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), frame->depth, 1);
    IplImage* r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), frame->depth, 1);
    cvSplit(frame, b, g, r, NULL);
    IplImage* bgr_plane[]   = { b, g, r };
    CvHistogram* histogram  = create_histogram(bgr_plane, mask);
    appearance.hist = histogram;
    cvReleaseImage(&b);
    cvReleaseImage(&g);
    cvReleaseImage(&r);
    cvResetImageROI(frame);
    cvResetImageROI(mask);
}
```

Note: `typedef IplImage* T_FRAME;`

Hence, I create two appearance models and compare their histograms:

```
void create_appearence( T_FRAME &frame, T_FRAME &mask, T_APPEARANCE &appearance, const T_RECT rect )
{
    set_histogram(frame, mask, appearance, rect);
}

float get_similarity( T_APPEARANCE &appearance_A, T_APPEARANCE &appearance_B )
{
    return cvCompareHist(appearance_A.hist, appearance_B.hist, CV_COMP_CHISQR);
}
```

As output, the program doesn't return value in `[0;1]` (for instance: `-41`, `14`, etc.), according (I suppose) to the definition of distance between histograms (see [`cvCompareHist`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/histograms.html#cvCompareHist)).

Is there a method to normalize these indices?

Regards, Vi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue, I'm using the **Bhattacharyya distance** (`CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA`) instead of the **Chi-Square**.

```
float get_similarity( T_APPEARANCE &appearance_A, T_APPEARANCE &appearance_B )
{
    return cvCompareHist(appearance_A.hist, appearance_B.hist, CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA);
}
```

So, `cvCompareHist` returns a value in `[0;1]`, as required.

Note that the method `CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA` only works with normalized histograms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sigmoid-like functions. They can compress any interval of values to [0;1].